# How to read mail in console

Tags: macos, terminal

I opened my Mac terminal and it said, "You have mail" . I didn't even know I could get mail in the console.  Does anyone know what command I can enter to read the mail?

Comment: Best answers are available here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2432/16253

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Shockingly, it's named... `mail`. :)

Comment: o.k. thanks, but that doesn't let me read it. anticipating the obvious, I typed "read" but nothing happened.

Comment: @Michael: just pressing "return" will read a message, or using the "p" (*print*) command. Try `man mail` at the terminal prompt for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 17):

at the command line prompt ("$"), type "mail" and then hit [Enter]
mail will then tell you how many emails you have waiting (possibly none).
enter the sequence number of the email you want to read (e.g., "1") and hit [Enter]
you will then be shown the text of the email.
To delete the email, once read, hit the "d" key and enter.
To exit 'mail', hit [Ctrl][d] to close the application

Answer (score 1):

To delete just type         `delete range`
e.g         `delete 1 - 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
open  /var/mail
vi /var/mail/apple
```